# Converting input textbox from an HTML table to all divs

Tags: html, css

How can I convert my table style input textbox to a bunch of divs that would resemble it?

```
<table style="border: 1px solid #000000;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input style="height: 17px; border: 0; width: 150px;" type="text"></td>
        <td style="padding-right: 2px;"><a style="color: red; text-decoration: none;" href="javascript:add()">+</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="textinput">
  <input type="text" />
  <div onclick="add()">+</div>
</div>
```

Here is HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/kUSBM/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 180px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000000;">

    <div style="float: left;"><input style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 3px; width: 160px; border: none;" type="text"></div>

    <div>+</div>

</div>
```